# Convert medical data from XML to CSV or JSON format?

Tags: json, csv, xml-parsing, nlp, data-science

This is a medical record of a patient with bunch of information about medical history, past, family etc. This is an XML file. I would like to get this is a json or CSV format.

Some records are reported in the same format with these topics and some are named a little differently in other records like 'Discharge Date and time' instead of just 'Discharge date' or have an additional topic like 'SURGERIES DONE' etc.

I've put 'xxxx' or '.....' where there are long lines of text about the patient (8-10 lines).

```
  <doc id="1">
<text>
490646815 | WMC | 31530471 | | 9629480 | xx/xx/xxxx xx:xx/:xx**strong text** AM | ANEMIA 
| Signed | DIS | Admission Date: xx/xx/xxxx Report Status: Signed
Discharge Date: xxxxx
ATTENDING: xxxx
PRINCIPAL DIAGNOSIS: xxx and xxx.
SECONDARY DIAGNOSES: Diabetes , xxxx.
HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS: The patient is xxxxx......
PRE-ADMISSION MEDICATIONS: Caltrate , xxx,.....
PAST MEDICAL HISTORY: Chronic xxxx....
FAMILY HISTORY: No family history xxxxx
SOCIAL HISTORY: She has xxxx
ALLERGIES: Codeine and Benadryl.
ADMISSION PHYSICAL EXAMINATION: Vital signs xxx....
STUDIES: EKG showed atrial fibrillation with slow ventricular
response with heart rate of 53 , widened QRS , a Q wave in aVL , and
U waves in the lateral leads......
PROCEDURE: xxxx.
HOSPITAL COURSE BY PROBLEM:
1.xxxx
2.xxx
3.xxx
DISCHARGE MEDICATIONS: Norvasc 5 mg daily , Caltrate plus.....
DISPOSITION: To home with services.
FOLLOW-UP APPOINTMENTS: The patient will follow up with xxxx
CODE STATUS: The patient is full code , and her healthcare proxy
is her daughter , xxxx
PRIMARY CARE PHYSICIAN: xxxxx
eScription document: 6xxxx
Dictated By: xxxx
Attending: xxxx
Dictation ID xxxx
D: 10/15/06
T: 10/10/06</text>
</doc>
```

Comment: If the only problem are the small changes in the fields names you could try and match the fields with some kind of edit distance. What other problems are you encountering? This doesn't seem like a complicated task from what you wrote.

Comment: I am unable to convert this XML file to CSV or json format.